# Update BIOS Z87X-OC Q-flash

Tags: motherboard, bios, flashing

I'm trying to fix some issues with my PC namely, the erratic CPU performance, power issues and graphics card malfunctions. I've been advised by the manufacturer of my PC to update the BIOS on my Gigabyte Z87X-OC BIOS from F3 to F9c as F3 does not support my current CPU (Intel K-series) and is known to be somewhat incompatible with my graphics card and PSU. (For more information: http://www.gigabyte.com.au/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4514&dl=1&RWD=0#bios)

I have a couple of concerns.

- The BIOS version I have downloaded i.e. F9c is in Beta. (This would potentially fix my CPU issues) Does anyone know what the potential issues are with the F9c version or where I could get the current bug/known issues list?
- When I go to the Q-flash menu in POST. I get the following options to run: 'autobat.bat', the actual BIOS file and 'efiflash.exe'. Which one should I select?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what issues exists, its stable enough that they released it, but its not the only version that supports it, F8 supports it or should you don't indicate which Intel product you have.

Comment: The [manual](http://www.gigabyte.com.au/webpage/20/images/utiltiy_qflash_uefi.pdf) seems pretty clear on how to use the Q-Flash program.

Comment: @Ramhound, the documentation doesn't clarify what to option to select when I'm in POST. Unless I'm missing something the manual seems to skip to pressing 'Reboot' once an option is selected.

Comment: What are the contents of the `autobat.bat`?

Comment: @Ramhound not sure but according to this it's not required. (http://forums.tweaktown.com/gigabyte/27576-bios-flashing-how-qflash-guide.html (`CTRL + F` to find the second occurence of `.bat`) **Disclaimer**: The link is quite old circa 2000

Comment: I need to know the contents of the file in order to answer your question.  Open the file in a text editor within Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound it contains the following line `Efiflash Z87XOC.F9c` which I assume runs `Efiflash.exe` on the BIOS file.

Comment: You will want to run the .bat file.